# sign of trace of product of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two square matrices and all eigenvalues of $A$ are positive and all eigenvalues of $B$ are negative, and $AB\neq BA$. Show  $$trace(AB)\leq 0$$

I  write eigenvalue decomposition of $A$ and $B$ as:
$A=\sum_i \lambda_i u_i$ and $B=\sum_j \mu_j v_j$ where $\lambda_i>0$ and $\mu_j\leq 0$ are eigenvalues and $u_i$ and $v_j$ are eigenvectores of $A$ and $B$ respectively. Hence,
$$trace(AB)=\sum_i\sum_j\lambda_i\mu_j|(u_i.v_j)|^2 \leq 0$$
But since $A$ and $B$ are not Hermitian, I am not sure if I am allowed to do this.

Comment: Your "eigenvalue decompositions" make no sense: you can't take a linear combination of vectors and get a matrix.

Comment: you are right, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true.  Try e.g.

$$ A = \pmatrix{1 & t\cr 0 & 2\cr}, \ B = \pmatrix{-2 & 1\cr 1 & -2\cr}$$

Eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$ and $2$, eigenvalues of $B$ are $-1$ and $-3$, 
$\text{Trace}(AB) = t-6$ is positive for $t > 6$ and negative for $t < 6$.